# LibreOffice command Line calc to PDF, no formulas

Tags: excel, command-line, libreoffice

I'm using PHP Spreadsheet to create Excel documents.
It works well.

But later on my script I need to convert those Excel files to PDF file.

I'm using this command line :

`libreoffice --headless --norestore --invisible --convert-to pdf:calc_pdf_Export --outdir files/pdf/ '.$path.'/'.$name.".xlsx"`

Until now I have no problem. But the fact is my Excel contains some formulas. They appear correctly on the Excel file, but when I convert it to PDF they did not appear it looks like LibreOffice dif not run them.

Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: I have tested the command for a sample .xlsx file, and it works fine for formulas. Could you provide a minimal working example?